How would you prove the formula for the number of paths on the surface of a rectangular solid?
I was reading a book the other day, when I came across a formula briefly mentioned the number of ways for an ant to crawl from the grid lines of the surface of a rectangular solid from one corner to another with dimensions $n\times m\times r$, with $r$ being the height.
The formula was
$$N = 2 \cdot \left( {m+n+r\choose{m}}+{m+n+r\choose{n}}+{m+n+r\choose{r}} \right) \\- 2 \cdot \left( {m+n\choose{n}}+{n+r\choose{r}}+{r+m\choose{m}}\right).$$
I think I have figured out where the $2 \cdot[ {m+n+r\choose{m}}+{m+n+r\choose{n}}+{m+n+r\choose{r}}]$ part comes from, as the first ${m+n+r\choose{m}}$ comes from the ways of ordering $n$ placeholders for the times you go in one direction, somewhat like finding the ways to do so on a 2d perspective, and doing the same with both m and n, allowing us to create a possible pattern of $\{n,n,n,m,r,m\}$ (this doesn't work because it goes into the solid). With the limitation that all $r$ have to come before $n$, but the $m$ can be scattered throughout would hopefully lead to the ant only traveling across the surface, since you would go up and to the side on one face, until you got all the way up to the top face, where then you could start moving sideways.
Such a path I am thinking of could look something like $\{r,m,r,r,m,r,r,r,n,m,n,n,n,m,n,n\}$, assuming a general number of $r$, $m$, and $n$, not the specific number I have mentioned. You would do the same for the rest of the numbers, and you would multiply by $2$ because it could be either be $n$ before $r$ or $r$ before $n$.
However, I am confused on why you would subtract $2 \cdot [{m+n\choose{n}}+{n+r\choose{r}}+{r+m\choose{m}}]$. Could somebody please explain why, or if there is a hole in my current logic? Thank you very much!

Hello! Please consider improving the layout and giving further details and explanations, this is a bit hard to read.

Aren't the terms of the right hand side cancelling the "forbidden" moves?

I'm not quite sure, because then there has to be a hole in my current logic... but I can't really find it.

Is there a typo in the ${m+n+r\choose{m}}+{m+n+r\choose{n}}+{m+n+r\choose{m}}$ part? I would expect that it would be ${m+n+r\choose{m}}+{m+n+r\choose{n}}+{m+n+r\choose{\color{red}r}}$.

Yes, fixed it. Thanks!

Let's call the rectangular solid a box for convenience.
Assume the edges of the box are parallel to the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system, let $(0,0,0)$ be the corner where the ant starts, and let $(n,m,r)$ be the corner where the ant ends its walk.
Assume the ant's walk is a sequence of $m + n + r$ segments,
each segment being parallel to one of the axes and increasing the corresponding coordinate by $1$.
Six of the edges of the box form a closed path $\gamma$ around the box that you can trace from $(0,m,0)$ to $(0,m,r)$ to $(0,0,r)$ to $(n,0,r)$ to $(n,0,0)$ to $(n,m,0)$ and finally back $(0,m,0)$. This path passes through every corner of the box except the corners where the ant's path starts and ends.
The ant has to cross over the path $\gamma$ in order to get to its destination.
Suppose the ant crosses over $\gamma$ along the edge from $(0,m,0)$ to $(0,m,r)$.
While doing this, the ant can only travel on the two faces of the box that meet at that edge. The possible paths then correspond one-to-one with the paths through a grid of size $(m + n) \times r$, which is $\dbinom{m+n+r}{r}$.
But there are five more edges of the box in $\gamma$. Count the number of ways to get to the destination across each edge. When the totals for all six edges are added together, we get
$$ 2\binom{m+n+r}{m} + 2\binom{m+n+r}{n} + 2\binom{m+n+r}{r}.  \tag1 $$
The reason that this is not the answer is that if the ant passes through one of the other six corners of the box on the way to corner $(n,m,r)$,
the ant will have passed over two edges and that path is counted twice in formula $(1)$.
For example, if a path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(n,m,r)$ passes through $(0,m,r)$ then it is counted once as one of the paths crossing the edge from $(0,m,0)$ to $(0,m,r)$ and it is also counted as one of the paths crossing the edge from $(0,m,r)$ to $(0,0,r)$.
If a path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(n,m,r)$ happens to pass through two other corners of the box, it will be counted three times, once for each of the edges that has an endpoint at one of those two corners. There are exactly six of these paths for any box.
So we need to subtract something to cancel out the number of times we overcounted a single path.
Consider the paths that go through $(0,m,0)$. There is only one way to get to $(0,m,0)$ from $(0,0,0)$, but once you are at $(0,m,0)$ there are $\dbinom{n+r}{r}$ ways to get to
$(n,m,r)$. So if we subtract $\dbinom{n+r}{r}$ from formula $(1)$
then we will cancel one of the times each path through $(0,m,0)$ was counted.
Do this for all six corners that the ant can pass through on its way
from $(0,0,0)$ to $(n,m,r)$. The total amount that gets subtracted in this way is
$$ 2 \binom{m+n}{n} + 2 \binom{n+r}{r} + 2 \binom{r+m}{m}. $$
Notice that if a path passes through two corners, it will get canceled twice. But in that case, the path was counted three times in formula $(1)$, so it turns out that we want to cancel it exactly twice.
So after this subtraction, we have the exact correct number of paths:
$$ 2\left(\binom{m+n+r}{m} + \binom{m+n+r}{n} + \binom{m+n+r}{r}
 - \binom{m+n}{n} - \binom{n+r}{r} - \binom{r+m}{m}\right). $$
